# Azure ASFS 2.0 Federated auth - How to allow access to css and js files during development

Tags: iis-7, wif, adfs2.0, azure-active-directory

I want to test my applications support of Azure ADFS, If add ASDF to my web.config , it doesnt allow me to download my CSS/Script files directly , it needs me go through bundling optimization, but at dev time i dont want optimization for obvious reasons. I tried adding allow access to folders in root web.config and adding web.config to individual folders (Scripts/Contents), but that didnt work. Any hint/help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting location allow config in web.cong wont work. Instead add `preCondition="integratedMode"` to `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` and `SessionAuthenticationModule` as shown below.

```
<modules>
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</modules>
```